# Simple SPARQL query on dbpedia results doesn't match expectations

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am struggling with the following SPARQL query executed via at [DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint](http://http//dbpedia.org/sparql):

```sql
select (count(?abstract) as ?count)
where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Linked_Data> dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract .
}
```

SPARQL seems pretty simple and when I look at the [linked data page](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Linked_data), it appears that expected result would be 9. But the actual response is 0. Is my understanding or expectation wrong? Could someone more experienced clarify please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nine abstracts on the linked data article, but the title of the article is "Linked data", not "Linked Data", and the capitalization matters.  Thus, you can do this, and see all nine abstracts getting counted:

```sql
select (count(?abstract) as ?nAbstract) {
  dbpedia:Linked_data dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%28count%28%3Fabstract%29%20as%20%3FnAbstract%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3ALinked_data%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The public endpoint defines the **dbpedia:** prefix.  It's short for http://dbpedia.org/resource, so **dbpedia:Linked_data** is just short for **http://dbpedia.org/resource/Linked_data**.   That's the URI for the resource, but when you put it into a web browser, you'll get redirected to a human readable HTML version at http://dbpedia.org/page/Linked_data.